# Second order linear inhomogeneous ODE with characteristic function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I'd like to calculate the solution $y : [0, \infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of the IVP
>
> $$\ddot{y}(t) -4\dot{y}(t)+4y(t) = t\mathrm e^{2t} \chi_{[0,1]}(t), \quad y(0) = 1,\ \dot{y}(0) = 0,$$
>
> where $\chi_{[0,1]}(t)$ is the indicator function on the interval $[0, 1].$

What I was able to do is to solve the homogenous equation $\ddot{y}(t) -4\dot{y}(t)+4y(t) = 0$. After this I wanted to find a particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation. My idea was, that I use the ansatz $y_{\mathrm p}(t) = f(t) \mathrm e^{2t}$, where $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$, plug this into the ODE and multiplicate the resulting solution with the characteristic function. That lead me to the particular solution $y_{\mathrm p}(t) = \frac{t^3}{6} \mathrm e^{2t} \chi_{[0,1]}(t)$, but I was told that this is wrong. What is my mistake and how can one solve this problem?

Comment: I guess it's wrong because $y_p$ is not differentiable. My first instinct would be to use Laplace transformation(Fourier transformation might work as well). This should sort out the discontinuous bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have $y_p\in C^2$.  At $t=1$, $\ddot y$ would have to abruptly change.

So the way to do this is to compute the solution $t\in[0,1)$ and $t\in[1,\infty)$ separately, and imposing a $C^1$ transition at $t=1$.

So for $t\in[0,1]$, the DE is
$$
\ddot{y}-4\dot y+4y = te^{2t}, y(0)=1, \dot{y}(0)=0
$$
giving $y=\frac16\exp(2t)(t^3-12t+6)$.  At $t=1$ this gives $y(1)=-5e^2/6$, $\dot y(1)=-19e^2/6$, so the solution to $\ddot{y}-4\dot y+4y=0$ on $[1,\infty)$ is
$$
y=\frac16\exp(2t)(4-9t)
$$